# excel formula help on counting unique dates between specified dates

Tags: excel, date, numbers, between, countif

I am writing an excel formula for work. I have an updating sheet that counts for the month's output for each person. I want to keep track of how many days they have worked. by counting the unique dates they input into the sheet but only between the month dates placed on the master lookup form. ex
the month is 01/01/2019 - 01/01/ 2019 column a contains dates entered by employee cell e2 contains months beginning cell d2 contains months end found by eomonth. I want to search dates in column a for dates between e2 - d2 and output in e3 number of days worked.

```
    =if(COUNTIFs(J3:J,J3:J&"",J3:J,">="&N2,J3:J,"<="&O2) = 0 ,"no days worked",SUMPRODUCT((J3:J<>"")/COUNTIFs(J3:J,J3:J&"",J3:J,">="&N2,J3:J,"<="&O2)))
```

is what I have so far. it keeps giving me the second part of sumproduct cannot be zero. but that formula is giving me 4 if used by itself based on the data set I am giving it. so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(OFFSET(INDEX(Dates,IFERROR(MATCH(Dstart,Dates,0),MATCH(Dstart,Dates,1)+1)),0,0,COUNTIFS(Dates,">=" & Dstart, Dates,"<=" & Dend)),OFFSET(INDEX(Dates,IFERROR(MATCH(Dstart,Dates,0),MATCH(Dstart,Dates,1)+1)),0,0,COUNTIFS(Dates,">=" & Dstart, Dates,"<=" & Dend)))>0))
```

In a largely unsuccessful bid to make this formula more readable a created named ranges as follows.

```
Dstart = your D2
Dend   = your E2
Dates  = your J:J
```

You may replace the names with the addresses. However, I do not recommend the use of J:J because these 3 characters represent 1.4 million cells referenced repeatedly. If your data is of smaller size I recommend to stick with a named range for them and limit the size of that range somewhat.
Note that the formula is bloated because it counts unique values only. Its action, in a nutshell, is to find the first cell to match Dstart, then establish the last cell by counting how many entries there are and, finally, count unique items within that range.

Comment: I tried using your formula and placing in the required cells and ranges. but for some reason, it is giving me the error did not find value 43466 in match evaluation. now I am assuming that value would be the serial date of the day we are looking for. but the output of the cell at current is n/a. how is this formula looking up the dates by text matching or serial conversion of the dates?

Comment: it may also be due to the fact there is a chance the original date does not show in the scale of data as not all employees work the same days. I don't know if the first date being missing from the list is causing a problem

Comment: #N/A indicates a match error. Therefore you might concentrate on IFERROR(MATCH(Dstart,Dates,0),MATCH(Dstart,Dates,1)+1)) and test it on its own. The formula looks for the Start date and selects the date before that if the exact date isn't found. #N/A would result if the second match also produces an error, meaning there is no date >= than DStart in the list.

Comment: would that not mean if the day before the first-month first day would search for last year and that's throwing the error?

Comment: The error would occur if the Start date is before the first date in the list. You can deal with that case by embedding the entire formula in an ISERROR() function which defines what to do in such a case.

Comment: In the following the error is converted to return row 1. IFERROR(IFERROR(MATCH(Dstart,Dates,0),MATCH(Dstart,Dates,1)+1),1). You should test out what errors occur and why and fix the formula in the way here described. Whether 1 is the correct start of the count range or not depends upon how your ranges are set up.

Comment: I did find the reason. The dstart date does not exist in the set lf data in column j. The first date for the employee is 1/3/2019. So how can i make the match increment higher if the dstart date is not found. Till it finds the first matching date? To cover gaps in the sheet.

Comment: Basically, the error - any error - means that there is nothing to sum up. The sum of nothing is zero. Therefore the solution might be to embed the entire formula in an ISERROR function that returns 0 when the formula throws and error, like, =ISERROR([above function without =], 0)

Comment: i am still unable to get this to work. if anyone can help ill link them my google sheet link. i have tried all kinds of versions of this code and it just wont do what i want.

Comment: I don't have access to Google but if you care to upload your workbook to a file sharing site, publish the link here and I shall download it. This is, BTW, presuming that you aren't trying to run the formula on Google Sheets in which case I can't help you.